# ASP.NET Core 1.0 Exception Filter Can't Make it Return 404

Tags: c#, exception, custom-attributes, asp.net-core-1.0

I have been trying to make an Exception Filter work by just simply returning a 404. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to return a 404 at all, instead it throws 500.

API Controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ItemNotFoundExceptionFilter]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    var _service = new CustomExeptionService();
    _service.ThrowItemNotFoundException();
    return Ok();
}
```

Custom Exception Service:

```
public class CustomExeptionService
{
    public void ThrowItemNotFoundException()
    {
        throw new ItemNotFoundException("This is a custom Exception.");
    }
}

public class ItemNotFoundException : Exception
{
    public ItemNotFoundException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public ItemNotFoundException(string message, Exception ex) : base(message, ex) { }
}
```

Exception Filter Attribute:

```
public class ItemNotFoundExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        HandleCustomException(context);
        base.OnException(context);
    }

    private void HandleCustomException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(ItemNotFoundException))
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside your `OnException` method, does it ever get called?

Comment: Yes OnException does indeed get called. In fact HandleCustomException also gets called and it does get into the if. `context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode` also gets set properly to a 404 but in my response through the web I am still seeing a 500 and not a 404.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. I think your code will work, if you clear the exception. Example:

```
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(TokenExpiredException))
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            context.Exception = null;
        }

        base.OnException(context);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out HttpResponseException does not exist for MVC 6.

David Fowlers Response:
https://twitter.com/YuvalItzchakov/status/614094855367581696

Unhandled exceptions flow out of the pipeline. You have to write your own middleware to do what you want with them.